# How can I tell what *.phtml file does what in the page?

Tags: template, css

I am working with an existing template and skin and I need to know what .phtml files correspond to what part of the page. I found header.phtml and that contains everything in the header block, but how can I tell what the other blocks use for phtml files?

Much thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you not yet aware of template hints.

To enable them go to Magento admin. Navigate to System\Configuration\Developer\Developer, switch to your website scope and you will see "Template Path Hints" option.